# Adding different values to array with loop in Visual basic

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I'm trying to add some values to array like this:

```
Dim i As Integer   
Dim numlist(5) As Double  

Dim num201401 As Double  
Dim num201402 As Double  
Dim num201403 As Double  
Dim num201404 As Double  
Dim num201405 As Double  
Dim num201406 As Double  

num201401 = 5  
num201402 = 7  
num201403 = 9  
num201404 = 8  
num201405 = 3  
num201406 = 10  

For i = 0 To 5  
    numlist(i) = num(20140+&i)  -->(This part is my question)  
Next
```

How can I assign a connection between i and my values (num201401 to num201406) ?

Comment: Just load the array directly and get rid of the `num#######` variables and the loop?

Comment: It is just an example. I have 150 variables

Comment: If you have 150 variables then your design is seriously flawed. You should probably be using arrays or some other container like a `Collection` or `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to assign variables to an array?

You just could do this:

```
Dim numlist(5) as Double

numlist(0) = 5
numlist(1) = 7
.
.
.
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm) is a explanation how to handle arrays.

Comment: First one: I have too much variables. I cannot add manuel. (at least it will take too much time that I don't want to lose)  
Secondly : Value of variable is changing (Like every customers has a different number but same numList)

Comment: I cannot see the problem. This sounds like a classic case for an array. whereas you use a bunch of variables or an array, you have to assign the values this way or another. The advantage of arrays is that you can loop through them and analyze values, edit them or assign another value...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reply.